# Почему учитывается порядок минусов и плюсов для начинающих?

Tags: обсуждение, дефект

Наткнулся на такой [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1424740/%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%bf%d1%83%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%83-%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0). У участника была всего 1 репутация и по правилам репутация ниже 1 упасть не может - это понятно

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне лчино вопрос показался интересным и я поставил голос за. Ожидал, что репутация автора станет равным `1 - 2 - 2 + 10 = 7`, но репутация стала равным 11, что для меня лично странно, потому что, если бы я первым проголосовал, то у него репутация была бы равна 7, т.к. сначала станет 11, что значит что репутация теперь может упасть, и два минуса отняли бы 4 балла

Я правильно понимаю, что если участник сначала будет так скажем "вредить" сообществу, то ему всё простится с первой же "пользой"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да. Репутация начисляется в том порядке, в каком ставились голоса.

Comment: Интересненько, а есть ли чуть более подробное объяснение почему? Может на англ. мете?

Comment: @ΝNL993, не знаю, не видел.

Comment: Тоже интересно, почему такое решение принято? Т.е. этот подход насколько я понимаю упрощает получение баллов для каждого пользователя. При честном подсчёте пришлось бы на сайте для каждого проходиться по всей его истории и подсчитывать голоса. Но это как-то не очень честно ли для начинающих, по крайней мере мне так кажется

Comment: Bias к поощрению. По идее хорошая вещь.